# SDN 3.3.0 with CDI; Use TransactionManager to Commit Returns CypherTransactionExecutionException

Tags: java, neo4j, cdi, spring-data-neo4j

I have tried to work with SDN 3.3.0 to get a graphdatabase, which i want to provide via cdi to use it without the complete Spring-Framework.

I produce my TransactionManager with this code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Neo4jConfigurationProvider {

@Resource(lookup = "rest/neo4j")
private String baseUriString;

@Produces
public GraphDatabase graphDatabase() {
    return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase(baseUriString);
}

@TXM
@Produces
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return graphDatabase().getTransactionManager();
}
}
```

I getting this Exception, by using the TransactionManager from SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase

> org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.CypherTransactionExecutionException:
>   Error executing statements: 404
>   {"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Transaction.UnknownId","message":"Unrecognized
>   transaction id. Transaction may have timed out and been rolled
>   back."}]}[{message={"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Transaction.UnknownId","message":"Unrecognized
>   transaction id. Transaction may have timed out and been rolled
>   back."}]}, code=Http.404}]

Usage of my TransactionManager:

```
@POST
@Consumes(PersonEntity.MEDIA_TYPE)
@Produces(PersonEntity.MEDIA_TYPE)
public Response create(PersonEntity entity) throws SystemException {
    try {
        transactionManager.begin();
        Response response = doCreate(checkValid(entity));
        transactionManager.commit();
        return response;
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw BadRequestException.fromConstraintViolationException(e);
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(formatMsg("create.persistence", e.getMessage()), e);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(formatMsg("create.persistence", e.getMessage()), e);
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(formatMsg("create.persistence", e.getMessage()), e);
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(formatMsg("create.persistence", e.getMessage()), e);
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(formatMsg("create.persistence", e.getMessage()), e);
    }
}

private Response doCreate(PersonEntity entity) {
    if (repository.findBySic(entity.getSic()) == null) {
        Person person = repository.save(new Person(entity.getSic(), entity.getGender(), getCurrentUsername()));
        return createResponseBuilder.build(person);
    } else {
        throw new ConflictException(formatMsg("create.conflict", entity.getSic()));
    }
}
```

My Provided TransactionManager is a RestCypherTransactionManager.

- begin() use only beginTx() from Transaction
- commit() use only tx.success() and tx.close()
- rollback() use only tx.failure() and tx.close()

Now my Question is: Why does my Transaction may have timed out or been rolled back? If you have a better way to manage Transactions in SDN 3.3.0 without the whole Spring-Framework (like @Transactional) please tell my how.

Btw.: Sometimes a mvn clean install works, sometimes not.

Comment: How long does your method take? First thing to understand if is really timeout... "sometimes works, sometimes not"... Based on your exception class the `TransactionManager` may be the `RestCypherTransactionManager`. so the timeout is actually defined by Neo4j Config "read_timeout", since Rest transactions are in fact based on Request... This is not a good solution advice, but try to increase this timeout value just to see what happens.

Comment: I increase the timeout to 18 secounds and nothing changes. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: Please, note that the default timeout, defined on `org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.Config` is 30 secs. Try to increase for 60 secs or so